# Show that the system has two different non-constant periodic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

for the system: 
$$ 
\dot{x}=y+x(1-(x^2+y^2))(4-(x^2+y^2))
$$
$$
\dot{y}=-x+y(1-(x^2+y^2))(4-(x^2+y^2))
$$

I have written the polar form as $\dot{\theta}=1$ and $\dot{r}=r(1-r^2)(4-r^2)$ and found the critical/fixed point to be (0,0). Normally I'd try applying Poincaré Bendixon but I have only seen that to be used for a single periodic solution.

[image]

The plot also leads me to apply PB but I just can't understand what the two different periodic solutions are that the question is asking me to show.

Is simply showcasing the periodic orbits $r=1$ and $r=4$ enough?

Comment: It is $\dot{r}=r(1-r^2)(4-r^2)$. So the periodic orbits are $r=1$ and $r=4$.

Comment: @JohnB : $r^2=4\implies r=2$, as the radius component of polar coordinates is always positive.